# What extra steps do I need to take to play and patch Crysis 2 on the PC?

Tags: pc, crysis-2, drm

I recently built a computer that should be able to run Crysis 2 very well. So I'm thinking about getting a physical copy of the PC version in order to experience Crysis 2 at its finest.

I'm worried about possible gotchas not listed on the box. Will I need to install additional software? Will I need an Origin account? How painful is the DRM? Basically, how many hoops do I have to jump through before I can start microwaving Ceph at 1920x1200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=143015) to [sources](http://www.overclock.net/t/945483/crysis-2-drm-any-info) I could find online, Crysis 2 uses [SecuROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecuROM) for disc checking, and uses [TAGES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag%C3%A8s) Solidshield to enforce a 5 activation limit per serial number.  It does not appear to use an always-on DRM scheme like Steam and Origin do.

The Steam edition removes the SecuRom, (as there is no disc) but keeps the TAGES DRM.

It seems like it's possible to "reclaim" some of the activations (ie, if you format and reinstall) if you're willing to get into contact with the publisher's customer support.